# Access other user's directories given their user id in linux

Tags: linux

Is it possible to access other user's directories for deleting files in it. This is for an application. I have user's id.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the proper permission of those files you can delete those files.

i.e

You are `root` user and want to delete another user's files than you can do that

Answer (score 0):

Below options,

1. If you are root or equivalent admin user, then your are a king and no one can stop you from doing anything.
2. If you are in sudoers list then probably you can try

`sudo rm <file path>`

This will work only if you are in sudoers list.